# Twig retreive all variabels translated in templates symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I use symfony 4 in my application web and now i have task for find all variabels translate in all files twig ??

for example I have array test content multiple variables:

```
{% for x in test %}
{{x|trans }}
{% endfor %}
```

and in other page I have array test2 content multiple variables:

```
{%for t in test2 %}
{{ t|trans }}
{% endfor %}
```

how to find all variabels translated in all templating ??

Thanks fro advanced

Comment: Of the top of my head `bin/console debug:translation`. Or in the profiler if you have it installed.

Comment: but this command only for display translated in console not to use in coding

Comment: if `test` is `['a', 'b']`. are you interested in getting `['a','b',...]`  or `['test','test2']` or maybe even `['x','t']` ?

Comment: They way you put it, you can't -- translation utility won't check dynamic references like that. If you have values in `test` predefined somewhere in PHP code, you still can use the utility but with a twist -- you need to import translator service and do explicit calls like this -- `$this->translator->trans("value")` -- in your code (https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#extracting-translation-contents-and-updating-catalogs-automatically). This way the tool can find your strings and dump them automatically.